# How to create a generic table of thrust::device_vectors

Tags: c++, c, cuda, thrust

I have created a struct to structure a table where the columns are thrust::device_vectors and gcc is complaining that I am not passing a template parameter.

```
struct table 
{
    thrust::device_vector *columns;
};

error: argument list for class template "thrust::device_vector" is missing
```

How can I make it generic that I could have any sort of arbitrary template parameters for each column?

For example, one table could have 2 columns: 1 float device vector and an integer device vector.

Comment: You might want to look into [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html), or [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to use Boost Any if I don't find a good solution on here.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesnt know which type of device_vector to create. You should use like this

```
template <typename T> 
struct table 
{ 
     thrust::device_vector<T> *columns; 
};
```

Comment: this answer will only allow columns of the same type and not diverse ones. hence, it would not support both int and double columns.

Comment: Thats exactly supports any type you pass to it while creating the object. what exactly you want to do is not clear? Can you paste a pseudo code about what you want to do ?

Comment: i want to generically create a table supporting arbitrary types for each device vector. for example i don't see how your solution solves this: a table consisting of device_vector<int>, device_vector<float>, device_vector<string>, device_vector<complex>,    
{ 
     thrust::device_vector<float> *col1; 
};